# How to set pages under a domain to another ip?

Tags: ip

Is that possible to set `example.com` to `ip1`

and then set `example.com/a-page` to `ip2`?

If that's possible, how can I do the settings?

Because I have a project is to build some webpages and then add to an exist website witch I cannot control...

Comment: No, that is not how it's done. You need to talk to whoever is in charge of the existing website, or else you need to use a subdomain. To start with, go learn some basics of web server configuration; look at the documentation for whatever webserver you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no control over example.com, then you cannot do this. At the very least you need to be able to configure example.com redirect/reverse proxy pages to your second server.

Comment: I cannot reach example.com 's redirect/proxy pages，but I still need to know how, I have to teach the web admin of first server, please help ><

Comment: Just use Google to look up for reverse proxy, you will find plenty of articles that explain how it is set with different software.